# PostgreSQL: "psql: error: FATAL: role "postgres" does not exist" error

Tags: postgresql

I am trying to install a second instance of Postgres server (v 12) on Windows 12 server.

I had executed the following steps as my user (friazsa)

**a, Created F:\PostgreSQL\Data_12_2 folder to house the data directory**

**b, Initialized the database**
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\initdb.exe" -D F:\PostgreSQL\Data_12_2 –W

Note:

- I was prompted for superuser password that I had supplied
- I am assuming superuser means postgress ???

**c, Started the PostgreSQL instance**

"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\pg_ctl.exe" -D "F:\PostgreSQL\Data_12_2" -l logfile start

Result: The instance had started.

**d, Updated the postgres.conf and pg_hba.conf files**

Here, I had changed the authentication method to md5.

**e, Tried connecting to the instance**

"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\psql" -U postgres -p 5433

```
Error:

C:\Users\friazsa>"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin\psql" -U postgres -p 5433
2020-12-30 10:25:41.659 EST [1392] FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
psql: error: FATAL:  role "postgres" does not exist
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you ran initdb.exe as OS user "friazsa" and didn't specify the `-U` option, then the name of the superuser is "friazsa".  If you want it to be "postgres", then delete your database (assuming you haven't yet put in any data you need to keep) and repeat initdb this time using `-U postgres`

Comment: Excuse the belated reply. Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for.